# Problem calling WebMethod in asp.Net Webform

Tags: javascript, webforms, root, multilingual, webmethod

I'm calling a WebMethod inside my application. Recently i changed the root config to upgrade the multilingual part.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {


         routes.MapPageRoute("languageHome","{language}/{page}","~/{page}.aspx");

    }
```

Since then it seem that i cannot call the WebMethod with jQuery

```
   function ShowNumeroLame() {
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "Home/GetNumeroLame",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             success: OnSuccessNumeroLame,
             error: function () {
             },
             failure: function (response) {
             }
         });
     }
```

I think that the problem is in the URL but i can't find it

Thanks, and sorry for my bad explanation

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem adding this:

```
url: '<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl("Home.aspx/GetSpessoriFette") %>',
```